# Выбрать строки MySQL, сумма значений столбца которых меньше или равна значению переменной PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть переменная php `$maximum_amount = 0.50000000`.

Есть таблица в базе mysql с названием 'orders', например:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|  OrderID |   UserID  |  amount      |  created_time       |
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|   a1bh   |    htl57  |  0.10000000  | 2020-07-27 08:23:11 |
|   2c3f   |    34gh7  |  0.30000000  | 2020-07-27 08:24:49 |
|   4d5s   |    lkr37  |  0.20000000  | 2020-07-27 08:29:03 |
|   5e6k   |    jkw68  |  0.50000000  | 2020-07-27 08:30:04 |
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Как выбрать строки из этой таблицы с лимитом 100, order ASC по `'created_time'`, чтобы сумма столбца `'amount'` выбранных строк не была больше значения переменной $maximum_amount?

Насколько я понимаю, нужно использовать куммулятивную сумму в mysql и сравнивать ее со значением переменной. Но пока не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Версию MySQL озвучьте, да... ну и создайте fiddle, чтобы два раза не бегать (в крайнем случае выложите CREATE TABLE таблицы, INSERT INTO тестовых данных, и покажите результат для именно этих данных).

Answer (score 1):

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';
$maximum_amount = 0.50000000

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select UserID, amount from table GROUP BY amount, UserID HAVING SUM(amount) < ? limit 100 order by created_time ASC');
    $stmt->execute([$maximum_amount]);
    foreach ($stmt as $row)
    {
        echo $row['UserID'] . ':' . $row['amount'] . "\n";
    }
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно так

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum_amount = 1.40000000;
    
   $this->db->from("(select *, (@sum := @sum + amount) as cume_amount
   from orders_table cross join
   (select @sum := 0) params
   order by amount 
   ) orders_table where cume_amount <= 1.40000000");
   $this->db->limit(100);
   $this->db->order_by("time_order_created", "ASC");
   $query = $this->db->get();
```